# Git error: unable to commit specific file - unable to create temporary file: Invalid argument, failed to insert into database, Unable to process path

Tags: windows, git

I have a Git repository which contains the lab work for a course I am currently completing.

Each week when I get given a task, I make an initial commit to push the given resources or any code that I am to make my additions to.

However, upon git commit the following Git error is thrown for an initial commit I am making:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in lab-04/bikky.py. The file will
have its original line endings in your working directory 
error: unable to create temporary file: Invalid argument 
error: lab-04/biscuit-043.jpg: failed to insert into database 
fatal: Unable to process path lab-04/biscuit-043.jpg
```

The LF warning is grand, I have addressed that.

It's the two `error` and the `fatal` warnings that I am unable to address, and I would like to ask what is going wrong here? What checks can I do to this file to figure out what is wrong?

I have ensured the file is present and not corrupted - it matches all other photos given. If I untrack this particular file, and so the commit commits successfully. I do not believe this is a permissions issue.

I realise this may be a question that is very specific to my repository, so I understand if the question is not suitable for SO but if there is anything I can add to get assistance - I will.

Comment: The root problem is the `error: unable to create temporary file: Invalid argument` failure. This is your OS raising an EINVAL error when Git tries to create a temporary file. Find out under which conditions this occurs in your OS. One problem that seems to be becoming commonplace these days is the use of fancy file systems like Dropbox: these don't work for Git, which needs a *local* file system in which to store the repository database.

Comment: Check that the file permissions assigned to `biscuit-043.jpg` are consistent with the other photos just in case there is something unexpected there. Depending on how important that file is you could also copy and rename another photo and just use that instead.